# How do I add totals/subtotals to a set of results without grouping the row data?

Tags: t-sql, grouping, rollup

I'm constructing a SQL query for a business report. I need to have both subtotals (grouped by file number) and grand totals on the report.

I'm entering unknown SQL territory, so this is a bit of a first attempt. The query I made is *almost* working. The only problem is that the entries are being grouped -- I need them separated in the report.

Here is my sample data:

```
FileNumber        Date   Cost   Charge
         3   Dec 22/09      5       10
         3   Jan 13/10      6       15
        3B   Mar 28/10      1        3
        3B   Mar 28/10      5       10
```

When I run this query

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (GROUPING(FileNumber) = 1) THEN NULL
        ELSE FileNumber
    END AS FileNumber,
    CASE
        WHEN (GROUPING(Date) = 1) THEN NULL
        ELSE Date
    END AS Date,
    SUM(Cost) AS Cost,
    SUM(Charge) AS Charge

    FROM SubtotalTesting
    GROUP BY FileNumber, Date WITH ROLLUP
    ORDER BY
        (CASE WHEN FileNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), -- Put NULLs after data
        FileNumber,
        (CASE WHEN Date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), -- Put NULLs after data
        Date
```

I get the following:

```
FileNumber        Date  Cost  Charge
         3   Dec 22/09     5      10
         3   Jan 13/10     6      15
         3        NULL    11      25
        3B   Mar 28/10     6      13 <--
        3B        NULL     6      13
      NULL        NULL    17      38
```

What I *want* is:

```
FileNumber        Date  Cost  Charge
         3   Dec 22/09     5      10
         3   Jan 13/10     6      15
         3        NULL    11      25
        3B   Mar 28/10     1       3 <--
        3B   Mar 28/10     5      10 <--
        3B        NULL     6      13
      NULL        NULL    17      38
```

I can clearly see *why* the entries are being grouped, but I have no idea how to separate them while still returning the subtotals and grand total.

I'm a bit green when it comes to doing advanced SQL queries like this, so if I'm taking the wrong approach to the problem by using `WITH ROLLUP`, please suggest some preferred alternatives -- you don't have to write the whole query for me, I just need some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH    SubtotalTesting (FileNumber, Date, Cost, Charge) AS
        (
        SELECT  '3', CAST('2009-22-12' AS DATETIME), 5, 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '3', '2010-13-06', 6, 15
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '3B', '2010-28-03', 1, 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '3B', '2010-28-03', 5, 10
        ),
        q AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY filenumber) AS rn
        FROM    SubTotalTesting
        )
SELECT  rn,
        CASE
                WHEN (GROUPING(FileNumber) = 1) THEN NULL
                ELSE FileNumber
        END AS FileNumber,
        CASE
                WHEN (GROUPING(Date) = 1) THEN NULL
                ELSE Date
        END AS Date,
        SUM(Cost) AS Cost,
        SUM(Charge) AS Charge
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        FileNumber, Date, rn WITH ROLLUP
HAVING  GROUPING(rn) <= GROUPING(Date)
ORDER BY
        (CASE WHEN FileNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        FileNumber,
        (CASE WHEN Date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        Date
```

Comment: (Stupid me.) I was just trying this by using `UNION ALL` on the source table with `SELECT ... SUM(Cost) ...` -- is your solution more efficient than that?

Comment: @JonS: `UNION` would require two passes so yes, this solution is more efficient.